# Does the See Clearly Method of vision improvement work?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, ophthalmology

I found a product called the [See Clearly Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BMWPTQ) on Amazon.

The program claims:

> The best personal vision improvement system currently available. The results of years of study and clinical experience, refined to a system of simple and practical steps, easy to learn and easy to do. This computer CD ROM includes: 1. Four Exercise Sessions 2. How to Get Started 3. Daily Progress Journal 4. Overview Video 5. Instruction Manual 6. Exercise Chart

Can one improve vision through exercises? Is there any validity to the claims of this program?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. Eye exercise programs of this kind do not work. Your eyes get enough exercise under normal conditions. There is no evidence that using glasses or contact lenses makes vision worse, and no evidence that special exercises make any difference.

http://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/the-lowdown-on-eye-exercises

One of the proponents of the Bates Method was Aldous Huxley. I've read somewhere an account of how he gave a lecture on the method and the great results he had with it. He appeared to be reading from notes, until half way through when he stumbled, paused, and started peering closely at his notes. It slowly dawned on the audience that he hadn't been reading, he had been reciting. Unfortunately I read this some years ago and I can't now recall where.